# Access: How can I count this as a full week (even if it's not technically)?

Tags: database, ms-access, datediff

I'm making some tweaks to our database, and I'm thoroughly stuck on this! Any help would be extremely appreciated. I'm terrible at all this, but I'm trying to learn. :)

I need to count the number of weeks that clients have worked. Currently I'm using this expression (please don't judge my awful amateur code -- it worked and that's all I wanted! lol):

```
Weeks_CurrentJob: IIf(IsNull([EmpEndDate]),DateDiff("ww",[EmpStartDate],Now()),DateDiff("ww",[EmpStartDate],[EmpEndDate]))
```

This works fine, except that it seems to only be counting full weeks. So, for example, 2016-10-05 as the EmpStartDate and 2016-11-03 as the EmpEndDate returns 4 weeks, but in our case, the government program would count that as 5 weeks:

The week starting Sunday, Oct 2nd; the week starting Oct 9th; the week starting Oct 16th; the week starting Oct 23rd; and the week starting Oct 30th.

Even just one day in each week counts as a full week.

I normally scour the web trying to solve my own issues, but in this case, I don't even really know what to search for! So any assistance would be beyond appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a 2nd Datediff to test for fractional weeks doing datediff in days, dividing by 7 and looking for a remainder.  If there is a remainder, add 1 to the first datediff, otherwise add 0.

IIf(Not IsNull([EmpEndDate]),(DateDiff("w",[EmpStartDate],[EmpEndDate])+(IIf(DateDiff("d",[EmpStartDate],[EmpEndDate]) Mod 7>0,1,0))),(DateDiff("w",[EmpStartDate],Now())+(IIf(DateDiff("d",[EmpStartDate],Now()) Mod 7>0,1,0))))

Comment: If anyone happens upon this question in future, I must note that this worked flawlessly, although I did need to change both the DateDiff("w") to DateDiff("ww").

I can't thank you enough, WryNoir!! You are absolutely brilliant. :) Thank you so very much!